# Creating Human Trafficking Heatmap in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, heat-map, density

I'm trying to create a heatmap with about 325 points distributed around the city of Houston. (FYI Houston is a major human trafficking in the US: a title shared with LA and Atlanta depending upon seasons and large events).

I'd like to plot the concentrations of these points, but can only get a large circular area around all of them with QGIS' heatmap plugin.

Currently, QGIS only allows whole numbers as its buffer ratio, so I would need to go smaller or possibly correct my CRS. The confirmed human trafficking addresses were geocoded with Google's API, and I have unsuccessfully tried in WGS84, WGS84/Mercator, and Google Mercator.

Is there a better way to do this? Here's a screen cap to illustrate. The results were the same for the aforementioned CRS's.

[image: heatmap fail]

PS. I'm also already aware that the current heatmap plugin can only create a raster layer with projected coordinates if the buffer ratio is in map units

Comment: Just curious, how did you get this data?  Is it collected by police?

Comment: My guess is that your cell output size is too high.
Perhaps, however, you will want to follow an actual tutorial: http://qgis.spatialthoughts.com/2012/07/tutorial-making-heatmaps-using-qgis-and.html

Comment: this was compiled by a nonprofit legal counsel for the city. the work was done over the course of last year, cross-referencing locations against multiple sites. i'm fairly confident of the general areas, but just not of the exact locations...hence the heatmap. here's [the original](http://childrenatrisk.org/research/child-trafficking/houstonsobs/)    

@geoist **addendums and corrections:** the _geographic_ CRS does not work with meters in the current version. projected works just fine. but projected CRS in qgis specify units=m.

Answer (score 2):

If you're curious, it was [Tutorial: Making Heatmaps using QGIS and GRASS](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/creating_heatmaps.html) that helped me learn more. Also, I heard back from the heatmap plugin's creator. Apparently he's been experiencing some bugs as well. If you're using the development version, it should be fixed in a few days.

Comment: Can you copy the relevant instructions, in case that link is broken?

Comment: The link was broken and moved as well, the link target is updated. 'Copying' the relevant instructions could be a legal issue, and excerpting the whole article here would be quite time consumin, so ....